# The Trinity $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_5), \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_7)$ and $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{11})$

Tags: reference-request, riemann-surfaces

Galois [proved](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/galois-last-letter) that $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_p)$ has a permutation action on $p$ elements for and only for
$$\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_5) \ \ \ \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_7)  \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{11}) $$
The [Klein quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_quartic) $X(7)=\mathbb{H}/\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_7)$ is an extremely interesting Riemann surface, which I know about. Thus I suspect that the three Riemann surfaces
$$X(5) \ \ \ X(7) \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ X(11)$$
should likely also satisfy remarkable properties.

Does anyone know what these properties are, and where I might read about them?

(I mean properties beyond just a simple ``taking the quotient of the Galois proof'', for instance for $X(7)$ its relation to modular forms, quaternions, representations of $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_7)$ etc.)

$$\text{}$$
(The title is a reference to [Arnold's Trinities](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/arnolds-trinities))

Comment: *The Eightfold Way: The Beauty of Klein's Quartic Curve* edited by Silvio Levy and published by CUP has a lot of interesting stuff on $X(7)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I know things about $X(7)$, the point of the question is about the whether there's something about the triple $X(5),X(7),X(11)$.

Comment: A better source is the ''Trinities'' section of the wikipedia page ''ADE classification''.